# Handled PreviewMouseUp event freezes WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I am listening to the PreviewMouseUp event of a ToggleButton control. Depending on a condition the click event should be raised normally or aborted completely. So the `IsChecked` property is only set if the condition is true. For this I use the `MouseButtonEventArgs.Handled` property that is set to false if the condition is false.

If the ToggleButton is clicked and the condition is false the IsChecked property is not set as expected. But the application freezes for no reason. No further button clicks are possible.

If you click into the taskbar (context lost) the application is working again.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonEventTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Content="Test Button" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Padding="10"
                      PreviewMouseUp="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseUp"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsMouseClickAllowed())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something that I am missing? Or is this a known WPF bug?

Comment: Perhaps it is not a bug, but just something you are not supposed to do. How about handling PreviewMouseDown instead?

Comment: You should avoid marking routed events as handled, especially if it is outside the scope of your custom control (as part of the internal control's logic). If you don't want the button to be clickable better disable it by setting IsEnabled to false. If you assign an ICommand to the button's Command property you can control this state very gracefully via the
CanExecute callback delegate.

Comment: Routed events are not like normal events that you handle on your own. They will traverse the UI tree. It's likely that other controls need to handle mouse click events too . By marking a routed events as handled i.e. cancelling them, you potentially affect other UI elements too. You should only react to the event but not cancel it.